# enabling developer mode in android emulator from command line

Tags: android, continuous-integration, ui-testing

Our Android app requires developer mode when running our tests (don't ask me why). So our tests fail on our build machine. Is there a way to enable developer mode from the command line when creating or starting the emulator?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "developer mode"?

Comment: @CommonsWare http://wccftech.com/enable-developer-options-in-android-6-marshmallow/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's enabled just by virtue of being an emulator. I do not recall ever having to do the seven-taps-on-the-build-number trick in an emulator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any adb command to enable developer options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510232/is-there-any-adb-command-to-enable-developer-options)