# command to hide developer options

Tags: android, adb

Samsung Galaxy s7 edge 7.0, (rooted)

I am looking for an adb command to hide developers options (i.e. remove the developer options completely).  I have reviewed all threads touching on the issue (enabling, mainly) on this and other forums.  the closest thing I have found is

[Is there any adb command to enable developer options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510232/is-there-any-adb-command-to-enable-developer-options)

I have tried inverting both methods listed with no success- someone else there asks about disabling also (no answer).  In practice, I assume what I want to do is clear data at the point

I assume such a command would also immediately? deactivate the adb shell.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, not sure if it works on non-rooted devices:

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.settings
```

Comment: Thanks - This did it - Developer Options menu is no longer present (until I bring it back).  Is clearing those settings likely to have any other effects?  (is this the same as clearing the <settings<apps<settings<storage - clear data action?)

Comment: Yes, basically, Developer Options data will be stored in a shared preference file of Setting application, the command will clear this file. As a result, the feature is gone.

Comment: @deficineiron, if it is ok, please mark it as the correct answer