# Fire OS enable unknown app installation via ADB

Tags: android, apk, adb, amazon-fire-tv, amazon-fire-os

I have a specific custom device that has a Fire OS vNext 7.0 (probably some kind of *Fire TV type* of the OS?) in it and I need to install my own APK into it.

I have an ADB access with **root**, but Developer Options are not enabled (I cannot access them), so I can't install the APK (`adb install` throws `INSTALL_FAILURE_USER_RESTRICTED`). I need to enable Developer Options to be able to enable installation of third party (unknown source) APKs.

I tried to tap the serial number 7 times in `Settings - Device and Software - About` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945212/how-do-i-enable-developer-options-and-adb-on-a-fire-phone), but it didn't do anything. I also tried to follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510232/is-there-any-adb-command-to-enable-developer-options), but the package `com.android.settings` does not have the `shared_prefs` directory that is mentioned there (and I didn't find any other settings package that would have such XML). I also tried to push the APK into the device, go to ADB shell (as root) and install via `pm` (ended up with the same result as `adb install`)

Is there any way how to either enable Developer Options so that they appear in the Settings menu, or how to directly enable unknown app installation? Or is there any other way how to install my APK?

*I know it may sound weird that I have root ADB access without the Developer Options enabled, but that's just how it is, I already got this device in this state.*

Comment: how/why are you running OS7 on a device but don't not if it's FireTV or not? If it's a FireTV based device, Dev Opts are under "My Fire TV" in Settings

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I am supposed to perform a security analysis of this custom device at work and I cannot publicly tell much about what it is -- but it's not a tablet nor a TV. I got ADB open (with root access), but cannot install apps (`adb install AAA.apk` fails, as well as `pm install AAA.apk` with the APK copied in the device). And I just feel like that if I have root access, I should be able to do pretty much anything on the device, including installing apps...