# How to enable "Always show crash dialog" in developer options on an Android emulator via adb commands?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

How to enable or disable a specific developer options using `adb`?

I have found some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510232/is-there-any-adb-command-to-enable-developer-options) saying to enable developer settings via `adb shell settings put global development_settings_enabled 1`. But how to enable a specific developer option?

For example, suppose I want to enable "Always show crash dialog" on an Android emulator. Except of physically switching the button, is it possible to programmatically enable it like using `adb` commands?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `adb shell settings list global` ...once with the option enabled and once with it disabled.

Maybe this one?

```
private static final String SHOW_FIRST_CRASH_DIALOG_KEY = "show_first_crash_dialog";
```

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings/tree/master/src/com/android/settings/development

Comment: Got it. You are correct. I used `adb shell settings list secure` and then compared the difference. The `show_first_crash_dialog_dev_option` option changed from 0 to 1.